# How to get content page from third party cms instead of SAP commerce cloud in spartcus?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Instead of getting content pages from sap commerce CMS need to fetch it from other 3rd party CMS. Is it possible some how in spartcus

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a different backend throughout the project, you can set your own `occBaseUrl` as environment variable. If only a CMS page provider is the target, you can provide your own version of `OccCmsPageAdapter` which uses a different URL.

```
{
  provide: CmsPageAdapter,
  useClass: YourOccCmsPageAdapter,
},
```

See more in docs: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/

Comment: Thank you ... If I change adapter and within adapter use custom normalizer and get same CmsStructureModel Observable ... Do you think any other challenge  would come apart from matching layout .... for content page only

Comment: @Sam I didn't do it so I don't know. But will be nice to read your feedback from this experience :)